# Почему выходит ClassNotFoundExeption, хотя пути прописаны верно?

Tags: java, исключения, jdbc, path

Ставлю jdbc драйвер. Положил его в папку Java в Program Files. Указал в classpath путь до файла. Выходит `ClassNotFoundExeption`. Пробую запустить с `-cp C:\Program Files\Java\postgresql-42.2.5.jar`, тоже выходит исключение. Запускаю через IntelliJ, `-cp` указывал в >`Edit Configuration` >`Program Arguments`

Comment: Добавьте команду которой запускаете `jar` и стэктрейс

Comment: @GVArt написано же, запускаю через intellij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю, что у вас указан путь до файла, но без имени самого файла

```
java -cp .;"C:\Program Files\Java\postgresql-42.2.5.jar" com.example.MyApp
```

Да и не очень хорошая идея класть jdbc-драйвера в Program Files.

Comment: С именем файла. Но без com.example.MyApp. Эта команда - это для запуска через cmd, или это для указания в IntelliJ в Program Arguments?

Comment: Обновил вопрос, написано про -cp

Comment: Попробуйте запустить через cmd. Если в командной строке сработает, значит проблема в IDE и стоит внимательнее изучить [инструкцию](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connecting-to-a-database.html) или обратиться в их службу поддержки.

Comment: Да. При запуске через cmd все получилось. Но почему classpath не работал?

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что IDEA сама управляет путями к зависимостям.

Comment: А почему не очень хорошая идея класть драйвера в PF?

Comment: @AntonSorokin этим вы загрязняете системное окружение. Каждый проект должен иметь своё окружение с изолированными в нём зависимостями.